# Regexp replace string surronded by spacial characters only

Tags: regex, replace

I am trying to replace a string that is surrounded by non word characters.

My target string is

```
;ab.ab,abb...
```

And I want to get result of

```
;[ab].[ab],abb...
```

Here is my pattern

```
s/([^\w]+)(ab)([^\w]+)/$1[$2]$3/g
```

But it does not replace second match because first match is ;ab. and second match is done on tail of ab,abb...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just use the [word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)?

```
s/\b(ab)\b/[$1]/g
```